# Grasshopper identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this grasshopper (although I'm not sure if it was really one) near a lake in Bangalore, back in mid April. This is the only picture i could get and since it's so well camouflaged I would like to point out that it's right in the middle. It had those very conspicuous green bands on either half of the dorsal side with longitudinal white pinstripes. It was around 10 cms in length. Can i get an ID please?

[image]

Comment: What's meaning of ` get an ID `?

Comment: @aircraft The OP is requesting that someone provide the taxonomic **id**entification of the grasshopper.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as a "long-headed grasshopper", and belongs to the species *[Acrida sp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrida)* Of the species I've been able to find images of so far, I think is most closely resembles

***Acrida conica*** 
[image]

and

***Acrida bicolor***
[image]

A full list of species for this genus can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrida).

Comment: @AdDate You're welcome! I'll keep trying to find an aerial view that more closely matches yours.

Comment: I think it might've been an Acrida bicolor . There is a good ariel view on Wikipedia but I can't seem to upload it. Could you confirm?

Comment: @AdDate I think it's close, but still not the right species. The bicolor definitely has the white streaks running down the body, however, it lacks other dominant patterns, such as the green gradients and thick, white trim, which is heavily demonstrated in your image. The reason why I suggested the *A. conica* was because it does carry this thick white trimming, and does show some streaks. But it does still lacks the gradients though, which would be characteristic of the true species, I believe.

Comment: I highly doubt it's A. Conica. That species is mostly found in Australia and New Guinea. I don't think it is found in India.